# Numpy RNG non-deterministic even when seeded

Tags: numpy, random, numpy-random

I'm using numpy.random for a Monte Carlo simulation where very small acceptance/rejection probabilities are possible. Although I'm seeding the RNG, I'm unable to reproduce the same sequence of random numbers. In numpy 1.15.1's documentation it says:

> Compatibility Guarantee: A fixed seed and a fixed series of calls to
> ‘RandomState’ methods using the same parameters will always produce
> the same results up to roundoff error except when the values were
> incorrect. Incorrect values will be fixed and the NumPy version in
> which the fix was made will be noted in the relevant docstring.
> Extension of existing parameter ranges and the addition of new
> parameters is allowed as long the previous behavior remains unchanged.

First of all, what do they mean by incorrect values? Second, how is roundoff error handled? Aren't values always rounded in precisely the same way? Is it possible at all that my code is not fully deterministic even though I provide a seed? I am certain that the seed is nowhere else reset because I provide my RNG object to each of my function as an argument.

Comment: *"...what do they mean by incorrect values?"*  If, for example, they found that `numpy.random.beta` for some parameters ranges was not actually generating samples from the requested beta distribution, they would consider that a bug that should be fixed.  Of course, such a fix would change the numbers generated by `numpy.random.beta`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I see now. So that wouldn't change the sequence for a given seed and given version, on the same machine.

Comment: You should take a look a [this email about numpy's random number generator policy](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/NEP-Random-Number-Generator-Policy-tt45637.html).  It explains some of the limitations of the policy.  (Read the full thread if you want to see what the future of numpy's random module might look like--and if you have the patience. :)

Comment: On a given platform, you should be able to reproduce a sequence. Is your code single-threaded? How do you seed the rng?

Comment: Why not provide a [mcve]? Instead of just telling us that you are getting some weird output, explain how we can generate that weird output so we can explore it.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl the code is single threaded. As I mention in the edit, the use of sets in the code induced extra randomness

Comment: @JohnColeman The problem was that I was unable to produce a minimal code with the same symptoms. Please see the edit: I used sets throughout the code and was picking randomly from those sets. The issue was that sets are unordered and the particular order of sets was uncontrollable thus random.

Comment: If that is the issue, then surely you are now able to make a [mcve] out of it and post an answer. It might help others. If not (or if it isn't worth your time) consider deleting the question.

Comment: Can you post an answer please?

Comment: @endolith, not sure what answer you're looking for. Essentially my problem here was that I picked from a random position from elements in a Python set structure. The order in the set structure is not guaranteed thus there was true randomness in the code.

Comment: @Botond Post an answer explaining what the solution to your problem was.  "I used sets throughout the code and was picking randomly from those sets. The issue was that sets are unordered and the particular order of sets was uncontrollable thus random."

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I used sets throughout the code and was picking randomly from those sets, throwing a random number to pick the index of an element. The issue was that sets are unordered and the particular order of sets was uncontrollable thus random.